# setIcon() changing Icon but not changing addressable DOM on map with large number of markers

Tags: javascript, dom, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I’m first changing the icon of a marker with `.setIcon()`.
Then I’m rotating the icon with:

```
$('img[src="https://' + thedomain +
    '/xplorit_common/assets/SVG/map_radar.svg"]').css({
  'transform': 'rotate(' + adj_offset_bearing + 'deg)',
});
```

Everything works just fine with a small number of markers. But when I have upwards of 200+ markers the icon will ***not*** rotate. The marker image ***does*** change but the `<img> src` attribute ***does not*** change when viewing Elements in Dev Tools( even when searching for map_radar.svg ). Which, circling back, makes sense as to the icon not rotating; since the value is not actually addressable in the DOM. But does not make sense that the "correct" icon ***is*** visible

I’ve beaten this horse to death and need some outside input. Any ideas?

Comment: Are all 200+ markers the same?  How are they created? Are they rotated the same amount? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, preferably a functional StackSnippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Set `optimized:false` option

If you use specific markers with custom icons with **`.svg`**, you can experiment some difficulties with large number of markers. To bypass this problem, you need to disable the optimized rendering property set by default when you build a marker. To do it, just add line `optimized:false` when you set each of your markers:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myLatlng,
   map: myGmap,
   icon: {url: mySvgIconUrl},
   optimized: false
});
```

Or do it with the `setOption()` method :

```
marker.setOptions({'optimized':false});
```

For more infos about it you can look **[this section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#optimize)**

Comment: PaulCrp you rule! Fixed the issue.
Happy holidays and may the new year shower you with prosperity!

Comment: Happy my answer helps you. If it's the good answer at you're question you can click on the check mark beside the answer (V button) to accept it (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)